# Python, appending to different lists while looping

Tags: python, file, os.walk

Is it possible to append to different lists while looping through multiple directories simultaneously? my code:

```
def trav(dir_1, dir_2):
    data_0= []
    data_1 = []
    for dir in [dir_1, dir_2]:
        for path, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
             for file in files:
                 for line in file:
                      data_0.append(line)
```

How do I append line from dir_1 -> data_0 and appand dir_2 -> data_1 using one loop, I know i can write two separate methods but would like to know if there is a more efficient, simpler way of doing it. I tried using chain from itertools, but no luck with that, any suggestiosn?

Comment: tried itertools.chain(), but couldn't quite understand how to append file contents to a specific list @AhsanulHaque

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want two loops its okay you can simply perform an `if`

```
def trav(dir_1, dir_2):
    data_0 = []
    data_1 = []
    for dir in [dir_1, dir_2]:
        current_dir = dir
        for path, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
             for file in files:
                 for line in file:
                      if current_dir == dir_1:
                          data_0.append(line)
                      else:
                          data_1.append(line)
```

another way could be:

```
def trav(dir_1, dir_2):
    data_0 = []
    data_1 = []
    for dir in [dir_1, dir_2]:
        if dir == dir_1:
            data = data_0
        else:
            data = data_1
        for path, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
             for file in files:
                 for line in file:
                     data.append(line)
```

Second one will run faster than the first one, since number of comparison needed will be lesser.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could make data a dict:

```
def trav(dir_1, dir_2):
    data = {}
    data[dir_1] = []
    data[dir_2] = []
    for dir in [dir_1, dir_2]:
        for path, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
             for file in files:
                 for line in file:
                      data[dir].append(line)
```

Or you could make data a `collections.defaultdict(list)`.  Then you wouldn't have to initialize the entries to empty lists.  Also, I would suggest you not use the name `dir` because of confusion with the built-in name.  There's no harm done here though, because it's a local variable.